# Need to find beam deflection of a steel tube

Tags: mechanical-engineering, beam, deflection

So i have a square tube of 40mm, 3mm wall thickness with a length of 1 meter. Both ends are fixed 25mm inwards. Load is 3kg centerpoint. Steel is SJ235.

I need to know the deflection of this beam.

Thought this would be easy to find in 2023, but apparently all that exists are crappy calculators. I did find some specs though: https://eurocodeapplied.com/design/en1993/chs-design-properties

Anyone have a good tool/software or suggestions how to calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

The formula is shown below. For load in the mid-span, set a = b. You need to figure out E, I yourself.

[image]
[image]